# How can I assign specific cloudlets to specific virtual macines in cloudsim?

Tags: java, cloud, cloudsim

I have some virtual machines that I splited them into some groups called "Virtual Clusters". Actually I have a list of Vm lists as bellow:

```
VCs = List <List<Vm>>
```

in the other hand, I have some cloudlets that I splited them into some groups called Workloads. Actually I have a list of cloudlet lists as bellow:

```
WDs = List <List<Cloudlets>>
```

now I need to assign the i*th* list of cloudlets to i*th* list of Virtual cluster. actually I need something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<VCs.size(); i++)
   for (int j=0; j<VCs.get(i).size(); j++){
   broker.submitVmList (Vcs.get(i));
   broker.submitCloudletList (Vcs.get(i).get(j);
   }
```

But it doesn't Work and at last it assign all cloudlets to all Vms respectivly!
how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following line of code in your loop:

```
broker.bindCloudletToVm(cloudlet[i].getCloudletId(),vm[i].getId());
```

Do this after you submit cloudlet list to the broker.